# How to use the result set from a stored procedure in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure (from mysql) with codeIgniter (3.0.4).
My issue is that I have always the message "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Here is my code

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $sql = "CALL setup_resource('{$p1}','{$p2}','{$p3}',@id)";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT @id as my_id");
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    $my_id = 0;
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) $my_id = $row['my_id'];
```

I'm trying to execute with SP and with @id retreive the id returned by my stored procedure => procedure seems that I cannot call another query in the same transaction.

I saw in many topic that CI does not handle correctly multiples query string, and advise tu use "next_results()" function but the result is the same (or I have a message "none next_result() you have to use more_results()").
Also saw that i should use multi_query function from mysqli but did not saw examples of it.

Did anyone have this issue ? What would be the workaround for codeIgniter to handle it?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: I had the same error when calling stored procedures. I had to `$this->db->close();` and then `$this->db->reconnect();` in my model.

Comment: Thanks I tried your workaround, in this case it solves the error displayed. But it makes me lose the benefit of the second request which depends on the 1st one. In fact i cannot have the returned id from the stored procedure if i close the connection with the database.